# scrollbar in web and mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can a scroll bar be implemented so that it works in the same manner in mobile and web applications?i.e.,scrolling of content should be done when we drag(mousewheel) the scrollable content and the thumb in the scroll bar. Also i want to customize the scroll bar i.e., the styling of the thumb and rail in scroll bar must be separate. I have tried tinyscrollbar.js, facescroll.js and nicescroll.js. Can anybody suggest a method?

Answer (score -1):

Use a well written, adopted and tested *jquery* plugin, you'll have less headaches.
Try [jquery perfect-scrollbar](http://www.yuiazu.net/perfect-scrollbar/) plugin, or see a list [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/scrollbar/) give them a try and choose for yourself.

For this kind of UI things, it is almost always best way to use a already written plugin. Because it would take too much time to implement one from stracth and you'll have all kind of bugs compatibility problems too.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with iScroll or Flexcroll.

Here are the examples : 
 http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/examples/simple/

http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

http://www.nacodes.com/2013/05/01/jQuery-CSS-Customizable-Scrollbar